# Clase interna de Java y clase anidada estática

Tags: java, clase, clase-anidada

¿Cuál es la principal diferencia entre una clase interna y una clase anidada estática en Java? ¿El diseño / implementación juega un papel en la elección de uno de estos

Answer (score 1):

Del [tutorial de Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> Las clases anidadas se dividen en dos categorías: estáticas y no estáticas. Las clases anidadas que se declaran estáticas simplemente se denominan clases anidadas estáticas. Las clases anidadas no estáticas se denominan clases internas.

Se accede a las clases anidadas estáticas utilizando el nombre de la clase adjunta:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass
```

Por ejemplo, para crear un objeto para la clase anidada estática, use esta sintaxis:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

Los objetos que son instancias de una clase interna existen dentro de una instancia de la clase externa. Considere las siguientes clases:

```
class OuterClass {
  ...
  class InnerClass {
    ...
   }
 }
```

Una instancia de InnerClass solo puede existir dentro de una instancia de OuterClass y tiene acceso directo a los métodos y campos de su instancia adjunta.

Para crear una instancia de una clase interna, primero debe crear una instancia de la clase externa. Luego, cree el objeto interno dentro del objeto externo con esta sintaxis:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

ver: [Tutorial de Java - Clases anidadas](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Para completar, tenga en cuenta que también existe una [clase interna sin una instancia de cierre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468856/is-it-true-that-every-inner-class-requires-an-enclosing-instance):

```
 class A {
   int t() {
     return 1;
   }
   static A a = new A() {
      int t() {
        return 2;
      }
   };
  }
```

Aquí, la `new A() { ... }` es una clase interna definida en un contexto estático y no tiene una instancia de cierre.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358/6999690